# How do I append data to a JObject in C#?

Tags: c#, json

So in C# I have created the following Json:

```
{
"timeline": {
    "headline": "Development timeline",
    "type": "default",
    "text": "timeline",
    "startDate": "12/12/2011",
    "date": [
        {
            "startDate": "2012,02,15",
            "endDate": "2012,04,19",
            "headline": "Development",
            "text": "Coding"
        },
        {
            "startDate": "2012,04,19",
            "endDate": "2012,07,25",
            "headline": "Development",
            "text": "Coding"
        },
        {
            "startDate": "2012,07,25",
            "endDate": "2012,10,26",
            "headline": "Development",
            "text": "Coding"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

using a JObject:

```
                jjson = new JObject(
               new JObject(
                new JProperty("timeline",
                    new JObject(
                    new JProperty("headline", "Development"),
                    new JProperty("type", "default"),
                    new JProperty("text", "timeline"),
                    new JProperty("startDate", "12/12/2011"),
                    new JProperty("date",
                        new JArray(
                        from p in timelineList
                        orderby p.releaseDate
                        select new JObject(
                            new JProperty("startDate", p.startDate),
                            new JProperty("endDate", p.endDate),
                            new JProperty("headline", p.headline),
                            new JProperty("text", p.text))                                
                            ))))));
```

Now I wish to add another section in date[] of the json object with a startdate/enddate
However I cant seem to be able to do so :(

I have tried to create another JArray just to test and see if it would append to my json but no luck as I get an error of: "Reference is not set to an instance of an object:

```
JArray dd = new JArray();
dd = (JArray) jjson["date"];
dd.Add("item 1,sdsds");
```

How can I add another property to my already created JSON?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your example `jjson` does not contain a `date` property, it contains only `timeline` property, so in your case it should be `((JSonObject)jjson["timeline"])["date"]`